# Pixabay API always showing same results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, api

I am using the code below with a search field (input) to get results back from Pixabay. Regardless of the keyword I use in my search I always get the same 5 results (see attached image). What am I missing? Any help much appreciated!

```js
var API_KEY = 'my_hidden_api_key',
  searchTerm,
  submitSearch = $('#cms_pixaSearchBtn'),
  boxPixaResults = $('#cms_displayPixaResults'),
  URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&safesearch=true&q="+encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
 
 
 
 submitSearch.click(function(){
  searchTerm = $('#cms_pixaSearchKeywords').val();
  console.log(searchTerm);
  
  $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
  if (parseInt(data.totalHits) > 0)
   $.each(data.hits, function(i, hit){ 
    console.log(hit.pageURL); 
    boxPixaResults.append('<img src="' + hit.previewURL + '" alt="">');
   });
  else
   console.log('No hits');
  }); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="cms_pixaSearchKeywords" type="text" value="">  
<input id="cms_pixaSearchBtn" type="button" value="search">

<div id="cms_displayPixaResults"></div>
```

[image: Pixabay API search results]

Comment: console.log(searchTerm); shows "Dinner"?

Comment: that was in a case where I used "Dinner" as search keyword. problem solved though, correct answer below. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&safesearch=true&q="+encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
```

is defined before the click handler is invoked:

```
submitSearch.click(function(){
        searchTerm = $('#cms_pixaSearchKeywords').val();
```

so `searchTerm` is empty.

and according to the [documentation](https://pixabay.com/api/docs/#api_search_images) if `q` is empty you get all images.

To fix:

```
submitSearch.click(function(){
        searchTerm = $('#cms_pixaSearchKeywords').val();
        URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&safesearch=true&q="+encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
```